# MySQL right outer join query

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have a query regarding a query in MySQL.

I have 2 tables one containing SalesRep details like name, email, etc. I have another table with the sales data which has reportDate, customers served and link to the salesrep via a foreign key. One thing to note is that the reportDate is always a friday.

So the requirement is this: I need to find sales data for a 13 week period for a given list of sales reps - with 0 as customers served if on a particular friday there is no data. The query result is consumed by a Java application which relies on the 13 rows of data per sales rep.

I have created a table with all the Friday dates populated and wrote a outer join like below:

```
select * from (
         select name, customersServed, reportDate 
         from Sales_Data salesData
         join `SALES_REPRESENTATIVE` salesRep on salesRep.`employeeId` = salesData.`employeeId`
         where employeeId = 1   
    ) as result 
    right outer join fridays on fridays.datefield = reportDate
    where fridays.datefield between '2014-10-01' and '2014-12-31'
   order by datefield
```

[image]

Now my doubts:

- Is there any way where i can get the name to be populated for all 13 rows in the above query?
- If there are 2 sales reps, I'd like to use a IN clause and expect 26 rows in total - 13 rows per sales person (even if there is no record for that person, I'd still like to see 13 rows of nulls), and 39 for 3 sales reps

Can these be done in MySql and if so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried removing this from your query: `where employeeId = 1   `? OR making it this: `where employeeId IN (1,2)`?

Comment: Tried that but with a right outer join, i won't get 26 rows (one for each sales rep). The query posted above is just to get the name and 0's for one user for all 13 fridays.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first select your lines (without customersServed) and then make an outer join for the customerServed

something like that:

```
select records.name, records.datefield, IFNULL(salesRep.customersServed,0)
from (
         select employeeId, name, datefield 
         from `SALES_REPRESENTATIVE`, fridays
         where fridays.datefield between '2014-10-01' and '2014-12-31'
         and employeeId in (...)
    ) as records 
    left outer join `Sales_Data` salesData on (salesData.employeeId = records.employeeId and salesData.reportDate = records.datefield)
   order by records.name, records.datefield
```

Comment: i know it's been 10 days.. but I took your idea and went with it with some modifications and got it to work. The trick was in the table which I used to cross join with Fridays. Came here just to mark this answered.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do 2 level nesting, in your nested query change to outer join for salesrep, so you have atleast 1 record for each rep, then a join with fridays without any condition to have atleast 13 record for each rep, then final right outer join with condition (fridays.datefield = innerfriday.datefield and (reportDate is null or reportDate=innerfriday.datefield))

Very inefficient, try to do it in code except for very small data.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the outer join on sales rep is not needed because i'll always know which sales reps to query for. And when we do a cross join, we won't have null reportDates and our table does not have null reportDate for any sales rep. But I will extend your approach to see if that gets me anywhere.